# Downloading photos and video clips from my Panasonic Lumix TZ10

Tags: windows, windows-xp

With my  old camera a Sony cybershot I was able to download photos and video clips using the Wizard. but when I use this with the Lumix it only downloads photos not the video clips.  I have used the Photo fun software to get round this but now means I have photos etc. in other places, but would prefer all my photos and videos to be in the folder where I have all my Sony stuff. Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in windows file explorer instead of those nasty wizards. Just press WinKey + E and it will open explorer (or right-click Start and click 'Explore'). Your device will be displayed like an additional drive. Look in the folders on the drive (displayed like 'Sony Cybershot) and you will find your photo's and video's there. From thereon, you can just copy and paste those image and video files like any other files on your pc.

Comment: Note that I'm reposting an answer that someone had deleted, it seems right to me